# Dividing data from one table to multiple storage

Tags: sql-server-2012, availability-groups, storage

I have the following tables:

- `[Table_A]`
- `[Table_A_Changes]`

The two tables are pretty large (more then 50GBs). The first one contains some data, and the second one records' changes.The database is in `FULL` recovery model (`AlwaysOn`).

`WRITES:`

1. `[Table_A]` - constantly/many
2. `[Table_A_Changes]` - constantly/many

`READS:`

1. `[Table_A]` - constantly (in 99% of the cases only data for the past 6 months)
2. `[Table_A_Changes]` - rearly (in 99% of the cases only data for the past month)

`UPDATES:`

1. `[Table_A]` - constantly/many (in 99% of the cases only data for the past few months)
2. `[Table_A_Changes]` - no updates

I am going to use a cloud storage where the fast storage is too expensive to hold all the data.

So, I want to store only the the new data in `[Table_A]` on fast storage, and the older data on slow/cheap storage.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Also, since the major part of the data is not (`read/update`) I want to perform only partial backups on the data stored into the fast storage only.Let's say a full backup each week and a partial backup each 12 hours.

I am looking both for storage and recovery strategies (any links are welcome, too).

Comment: Partitioning with a sliding window?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new table `Table_A_Archive` with exactly the same schema as `Table_A_Changes`.  Partition both these tables by, say, one-month date ranges.  As data becomes stale in `Table_A_Changes` swap that partition out and swap it into `Table_A_Archive`.  Your data retention policy can be efficiently enforced this way, too.

A view which unions the two tables can make querying simpler.

Comment: +1 May want to partition `Table_A` as well (perhaps with bigger windows) - not for data movement but to make some of the query patterns benefit from partition elimination.